# Javascript Regex, Add space before and after math operators if there is none

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, math

Im trying to make the perfect math parser for my discord bot.

Currently I have a simple function parser that takes in a string which has a ton of `.replace` methods to clear up a bunch of junk or formatting things leftover from discord, or just replaces {} with () and such quality of life things...

```js
var parseArgs = args.toLowerCase().replace(/ -o/g, "").replace(/x/g, "*").replace(/[a-z]/g, "")
    .replace(/{/g, "(").replace(/}/g, ")").replace(/\[/g, "(").replace(/]/g, ")").replace(/\+=/g, "+")
    .replace(/-=/g, "-").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/`/g, "").replace(/"/g, "");

var origArgs = args.toLowerCase().replace(/`/g, "").replace(/ -o/g, "");

const output = parseMath(parseArgs);
```

This is nice and all, but If you input an equation like this: 
`!math 1 + 1aaa+aaaa2{55>>2}`

The parser will output:
`1 + 1+2*(55>>2)`

I want it to output:
`1 + 1 + 2 * (55 >> 2)`

Which easily gets parsed by my function, but the equation is sent into the chat, and its quite ugly.

Im asking if theres a simple regex formula to check if a math operator (`+ - / * x ( ) >> ^ += -= == ===`) like those is between any numbers

so `1+2/3(4>>2)` and `3>>4===3*4` will turn into `1 + 2 / 3 (4 >> 2)` and `3 >> 4 === 3 * 4` respectively.

Edit: I see how crappy my replaces are, so I simplified them:

```js
var parseArgs = args.toLowerCase().replace(/x/g, "*").replace(/ -o|[a-z]|"|'|`/g, "")
    .replace(/{|\[/g, "(").replace(/}|]/g, ")").replace(/\+=/g, "+").replace(/-=/g, "-");
var origArgs = args.toLowerCase().replace(/ -o|`/g, "");
```

Comment: What sort of output do you want for `!math 1 + 1aaa+aaaa2`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance read near the end of the post. But if you want it for specifically that formula, I would want it to be "1 + 1 + 2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove anything that isn't mathematical (remove anything that isn't a number or a possible operator), then use `.replace` to match zero or more spaces, followed by any of the operators, then match zero or more spaces again, and replace with the operator with one space on each side:

```js
const parse = (args) => {
  const argsWithOnlyMath = args.replace(/[^\d+\-\/*x()>^=]/g, ' ');
  const spacedArgs = argsWithOnlyMath
    .replace(/\s*(\D+)\s*/g, ' $1 ') // add spaces
    .replace(/ +/g, ' ') // ensure no duplicate spaces
    .replace(/\( /g, '(') // remove space after (
    .replace(/ \)/g, ')'); // remove space before )
  console.log(spacedArgs);
};
parse('!math 1 + 1aaa+aaaa2(55>>2)');
parse(' 1+2/3(4>>2) ');
parse('3>>4===3*4');
```

To also add spaces before `(` and after `)`, just add more `.replace`s:

```js
const parse = (args) => {
  const argsWithOnlyMath = args.replace(/[^\d+\-\/*x()>^=]/g, ' ');
  const spacedArgs = argsWithOnlyMath
    .replace(/\s*(\D+)\s*/g, ' $1 ') // add spaces
    .replace(/\(/g, ' (') // add space before (
    .replace(/\)/g, ') ') // add space after )
    .replace(/ +/g, ' ') // ensure no duplicate spaces
    .replace(/\( /g, '(') // remove space after (
    .replace(/ \)/g, ')'); // remove space before )
  console.log(spacedArgs);
};
parse('!math 1 + 1aaa+aaaa2(55>>2)');
parse(' 1+2/3(4>>2) *()');
parse('3*()');
```

Comment: Its perfect, but what about (). In the output, I can see spaces around parenthesis.... might need custom regex just for those

Comment: Yeah, since the `()`s have slightly different rules, add another `.replace` for them afterwards

Comment: I see the edit, yes its perfect, thanks a ton. I might need to go to regex tester and explore those first two formulas, but other than that its perfect.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but I do have another question about the formula. Due to how my parser works, it places math operators in between numbers and parenthesis. So 3() becomes 3 * (). However, it sees your equation does not do this, and instead outputs 3 *(). Got any ideas on how I can fix this?